# How to convert from ICU to Language Tag in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, intl

I'm working on a Symfony application where I have a language selector, everything is ok so far, but then I'm using a 3rd party system where I have to convert the value of the options inside the selector from ICU to RFC 5646, here is a piece from my code for better understanding:

```
<select>
   <option>Please select</option>
   <option value="en">English</option>
   <option value="es">European Spanish</option>
   <option value="es_419">Latin American Spanish</option>
   <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

Now, I have to send to the 3rd party system something like this: `es-ES`, `es-MX`, `en-GB`, `en-US`.

I'm using `Symfony\Component\Intl` with this function `$languageCodes = Intl::getLanguageBundle()->getLanguageNames();` to get the content of the select and just filling it with a `for` statement in Twig, I know a simple solution could be just hardcode the RFC5646 tags, but the project is way too big and we are using ICU in other parts of the application, besides, this language selector is way too important to be hardcoded (and too large as well).

Therefore my question is, is there any package or function to find the equivalence from php-intl ICU code to RFC 5646?
Thanks in advance.
Bests.